# Bash split and sort by two columns in same file

Tags: bash

For my file which looks like this:

```
AABBCC    10    5    CCAABB    100
BBCCAA    4     2    AABBCC    50
CCAABB    16    8    BBCCAA    20
```

... I am trying to sort columns 4 and 5, by matching column 4 to column 1.

Ideally this would return:

```
AABBCC    10    5    AABBCC    50
BBCCAA    4     2    BBCCAA    20
CCAABB    16    8    CCAABB    100
```

I have tried using sort, however as far as I'm aware it doesn't have a utility to sort within files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that file a TSV (tab-separated values), or fixed-width columns (aligned with spaces)?

Comment: Post your code that you tried with `sort`.

Comment: @Inian: OP is right, you can't do this with sort alone, so it makes little sense to post it.

Comment: It's tab separated in my file but I posted it as space delim

Comment: I tried: sort -k1 file but I wasn't sure how to split it at column 4 to sort and append back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
join -t $'\t' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2 <(cut -f1-3 file.tsv | sort -k 1,1) <(cut -f4- file.tsv | sort -k 1,1) | sort
```

Cut the original file, then join on the first field of both. We need to specify the full join fields in `-o` to preserve the first column, or `join` will eat it.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I wasn't able to save the output to file though ( > otherfile.tsv ), is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should have been able to. What happened? Was there an error? Which? What was the exact full command you issued?

Comment: On a larger file `join: /dev/fd/62:13: is not sorted:` showed up. I just changed the fields from `-f1-3 & -f4-` to `-f1-19 & -f20-25`. I should also mention my columns 20-25 are a smaller subset of column 1

Comment: Hmm... try to toss in the `-k 1,1` option into both sub-sorts. (Not needed for the final sort.) `join` is a bit particular about the two input files being sorted on the joined column, and _nothing else_ (and `sort` default is to sort on first column, but break ties with the rest of the fields)

Comment: Excellent, the `-k 1,1` options worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$4]=$5; next }$1 in a{ print $1,$2,$3,$1,a[$1] }' file1 OFS="\t" file1
```

The output:

```
AABBCC  10      5       AABBCC  50
BBCCAA  4       2       BBCCAA  20
CCAABB  16      8       CCAABB  100
```

---

You may pipe to `sort` at the end: `... | sort`

Answer (score 2):

With bash and GNU paste:

With temporary files for illustration:

```
cut -f 1-3 file | sort > file_1to3
cut -f 4-5 file | sort > file_4to5
paste -d '\t' file_1to3 file_4to5
```

Without temporary files:

```
paste -d '\t' <(cut -f 1-3 file | sort) <(cut -f 4-5 file | sort)
```

Output:

```
AABBCC  10      5       AABBCC  50
BBCCAA  4       2       BBCCAA  20
CCAABB  16      8       CCAABB  100
```

Comment: Note: this only works in the special case when inventory of column 4 is a perfect permutation of column 1.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that condition.